# Simple jquery event binding not working anymore

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mouseevent, jquery, datatables

I used to bind a click event on a table row like this :

```
$('#example tbody > tr').on('click', function() {
    console.log("i clicked on a row");
});
```

But it's not working anymore. I re-tried jQuery from 1.8.0 to 1.9.1 (latest) and it does nothing. I checked if it was twitter-bootstrap (retrieved from bootstrapcdn) : from 2.1.0 to 2.3.1 nothing changed.

My test config is FireFox/Chrome latests. The website is running on symfony2 with jQuery plus twitter bootstrap and Datatables plugins/css.

So, questions:

1. How to debug that ?
2. Any solution ?

Comment: Are you replacing/moving the rows or adding new rows after the event is bound? are you waiting until document ready to bind the code?

Comment: Make sure the selector returns a value. Programatically trigger a click event using .click()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct way of calling delegated `on` event is ..delegating it to the nearest static element..

try this

```
 $(function(){ //incase you missed the doc.ready
   $('#example tbody').on('click','tr', function () {
    console.log("i clicked on a row");
   });
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','#example tbody tr', function () {
  console.log("i clicked on a row");
});
```

the first `on` is better and faster then the second one.. just that when event is called.. the element where the click is delegated needs to be present in the document..

Comment: Exact. I checked the jquery doc further. I was using .live before switching to a new jquery version (.live is depreciated) and it seems i read the "on" doc too fast. Thank you :)